# CakePHP - Only one Query from external Model

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I've two Models:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User', 
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );      
}
```

and

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany = 'Post';
}
```

Now I'm having a problem with a query in the `PostsController`. I've an `add()` function and the view add.ctp which is basically a form. Now I would like to show some User information in that form.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Posts';
    var $helper = array('Html', 'Form');
    var $uses = array('User');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    function add() {
        $user_id = 1;
        $this->set('user', $this->User->findById($user_id));
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now the add-view-page shows that actually two queries where triggered. So if I `print_r($user)` within the add-view I'm getting an array with two arrays. One for a Post with user_id = 1 and one for the actual User with id = 1. But I would like to get only the User id = 1.

Comment: Where you like to get the User with id 1? In `PostsController::add()`?

Comment: Sorry, `$user` is from view, I'm  correct?

Comment: Yes, $user is from view and I want to have an array with the User with id = 1 in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `recursive` to `false` on the `User` model before calling `findById`, so you won't get any data from associated models. Like this:

```
function add() {
    $user_id = 1;
    $this->User->recursive = false;
    $this->set('user', $this->User->findById($user_id));
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now there is only the User array in the view available, but when I'm saving the from of the add-view now .. I'm getting a Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object in /home/app/Controller/PostssController.php on line 17.

Comment: Is line 17 this one: `$this->Post->save($this->request->data)`? If it is, it means it can't find the `Post` model, which is very strange (it should be available automatically). But you can always add it to the `$uses` array at the top of your controller. There is something strange about your naming scheme that could be making cake not find the model: is your controller file really called `PostssController.php`, with two `s`?

Comment: These two s just happend because I renamed the file in that error by mistake. But your right when I add Post to $uses, for some reason only then its works and the data is saved. As you said Post should actually be already available inside PostsController. I've no clue.

Comment: @JonasMillan, another possible reason: cake won't find the model if the file not named `/app/Model/Post.php` in cake 2.x.

Comment: Okay for some reason $uses needs to get its actual Model passed on as well. So finally its works fine for me - thanks!